# Why does Xcode keep inserting control characters into my code?

Tags: xcode

Every now and then, when I try to build my Xcode project, I'll get inexplicable syntax errors. Then, when I run `git diff`, I see that Xcode has inserted a ^S (hex 0x13) into the source file, right where the syntax error is being reported!

[image: Screenshot]

Does anybody know why this happens? Perhaps I'm accidentally hitting a keyboard shortcut for "insert binary garbage here"?

The character is always a 0x13, and it always shows up at the end of a line.